# d3.js + jquery IE 10 fails to deliver keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

[Here in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qAHC2/292/), when I have pure JS, the keydown event is delivered without any problem. However when I select jquery 2.1.0, it stops delivering the keydown event.

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 300);

d3.select("body")
    .on("keydown", function() {
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("x","5")
            .attr("y","150")
            .style("font-size","50px")
            .text("keyCode: " + d3.event.keyCode)  
          .transition().duration(2000)
            .style("font-size","5px")
            .style("fill-opacity",".1")
          .remove();
    });
```

It works fine with FF and Chrome though. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue!

Comment: I also noticed that it works sometime and do not work sometime in the fiddle. In my actual code however it does not work at all. I thought I had nailed the root cause with this, but looks like there is more to it. Will do some more trials and update the question.